# How to insert Date&Time by using keyboard of Mac?

Tags: macos

I mean the basic keyboard of osx.

Just like the command + shift + D to insert the Date&Time on onenote.

Is there any software to write a script for the keyboard??

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well but was able to get it done via Apple Automator on the Mac after a bit of research:

Create new Apple Automator Quick Action
Select Run Apple Script
Set Workflow receives “no input”
Select “Output replaces selected text”
Paste the following script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set thedate to ((current date) as «class isot» as string)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke thedate
    end tell
end run
```

Run it in the Automator app to confirm it is working.
Save Automator Quick Action as “Insert Current Date Time as ISO”
In System “Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts” create a new app shortcut by clicking on the plus + sign and selecting the app “Automator”. Use the exact name of the Automator file “Insert Current Date Time as ISO” or whatever you called it.
Give it a shortcut key of preference - mine is command-alt-d
In Keyboard Shortcuts, go to the Services section and repeat the addition of the shortcut under the Text section.
Save all and test. Should give you this format: 2023-06-17T15:19:29.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
Insert a line break without starting a new paragraph.

Shift + Return

Insert a line break.

Shift + Return

Insert the current date.

COMMAND + D

Insert the current date and time.

COMMAND + Shift + D

Insert or edit a link.

COMMAND + K
```

**Refer:**https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/OneNote-for-Mac-keyboard-shortcuts-20fa1619-0f1c-4f83-a3cc-41e12b366f2f?CorrelationId=973ad525-a512-4114-8b84-694112bc6812&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: No, I meant I can insert this any time but not only using onenote, don't need to use command + shift+ d but other hotkeys..